# How to filter on STRING column using BETWEEN clause in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Consider a sample pandas dataframe as below -

```
import pandas as pd
money = [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100,1200]
batch_code = ['B1_2023','B2_2023','B3_2023','B4_2023','B1_2024','B2_2024','B3_2024','B4_2024','B1_2025','B2_2025','B3_2025','B4_2025']
test_df = pd.DataFrame([money,batch_code]).T
test_df.columns = ['money','batch_code']
test_df.money = test_df.money.astype(int)
```

Here is the how the data looks like -

[image]

I want to `filter` this data on column batch_code using 2 parameters - from_batch and to_batch.

For example -

```
from_batch = B3_2023
to_batch = B4_2024
```

Then my output data frame should consist of all the records that are in between B3_2024 and B3_2024. The batches represents quarters but are coded with prefix B. How can I achieve this in pandas?

I tried writing

```
test_df[test_df.batch_code.between('B3_2023','B4_2024')]
```

but I got this as output, which seems to be incorrect -

[image]

The correct output would be -

[image]

**NOTE** - The maximum range of prefix quarters is B1 to B4 only.

Comment: Clean your data. If it was `'YYYY_BQ'` then it would sort lexically.

Comment: good suggestion. I can try that out. Would I need the data to be always sorted in order to follow the pattern `yyyy_BQ` ?

Comment: The data doesn't need to be sorted, you just need to ensure that the logical order of the values corresponds to their lexicographic order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change the data source, you can use [`PeriodIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.html) with [*boolean indexing*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) :

```
pidx = pd.PeriodIndex(
    test_df["batch_code"].str.replace(r"B(\d)_(\d+)", r"\2Q\1", regex=True), freq="Q"
)

from_batch, to_batch = "2023Q3", "2024Q4"

out = test_df.loc[pd.Series(pidx).between(from_batch, to_batch)]
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   money batch_code
2    300    B3_2023
3    400    B4_2023
4    500    B1_2024
5    600    B2_2024
6    700    B3_2024
7    800    B4_2024
```